# Android Youtube API thumbnail crash

Tags: android

when I initialize youTubeThumbnailView, I found this exception

My code is :

```
youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                }
            });
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.i(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.k(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.p.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView$a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
```

Comment: Are you using YouTubeThumbnailView in a list?

Comment: Have you registered you app on google developer console ? is this your api key ?