# Getting error while trying to make list of youtube video

Tags: android, listview, youtube, android-arrayadapter

I want to show list of youtube videos

**Item XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/model_black"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/large_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_thumbnail"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video_title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_margin" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter code**

```
public class VideoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
    YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Video> data = new ArrayList<Video>();
private Map<View, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> mLoaders = new HashMap<View, YouTubeThumbnailLoader>();

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView diyTitle;
    YouTubeThumbnailView  youTubeThumbnailView ;
}

public VideoListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Video> data) {

    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_video, null);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.diyTitle                 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
    holder.youTubeThumbnailView     = (YouTubeThumbnailView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);

    final Video current = data.get(position);

    holder.diyTitle.setText(current.getEnglishTitle());

    holder.youTubeThumbnailView.setTag(current.getValue());
    holder.youTubeThumbnailView .initialize(AppConstants.YOUTUBE_KEY, this);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return data.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {

    // TODO
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {

    String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
    mLoaders.put(view, loader);
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon);
    loader.setVideo(videoId);
}
}
```

**Exception**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.assiakitchen.view.adapter.VideoListAdapter.getView(VideoListAdapter.java:50)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2306)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1155)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1337)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1042)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5960)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView that is not a Fragment
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4822)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    ... 55 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Can any one help please?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are problem in XML file,

You have to add,

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
.....
.....
/>
```

in place of

```
<fragment
```

Comment: When I do what you said I got the exception in the following post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299743/android-youtube-api-thumbnail-crash